# Loading Bitmap by name in Android

Tags: android, java

Currently, I'm loading images as follows:

```
sampleimage= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.sampleimage);
```

This automatically chooses the correct image from the drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi or drawable-ldpi folders.

How can I load the bitmap using the image name as the string "sampleimage.png"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access bitmaps by full file name you can store them in `assets` folder. Then obtain *AssetManager* from your *Activity* by calling `getAssets()` and use `AssetManager.open(String fileName)` or `AssetManager.openFd(...)` method.

If you only want to force Android to not get bitmap from mdpi, ldpi and hdpi folders (depending on device parameters) then store your resources in `res/drawable` folder (without "-*dpi" suffix). You can also provide bitmaps in `res/raw` folder and then they wouldn't be scaled (what may occure in res/drawable folder).

There is one more difference between assets and res/drawable or res/raw folder. In assets resources can be put in subfolders in your way of organizing thins.

Look for more info at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html
and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html